# USART communication with a STM32f1xx

Tags: c, stm32

I try to achieve an USART communication. So I connect the RX of my STM32f1 with his TX.
Also I write a program for this communication. This code is composed of the following components:

1. RCC configuration
2. GPIO configuration
3. USART configuration
4. Send and receive of a string
5. Comparison between the sent string and the received string
6. Test if the communication succeeded => LED4 turn on else the LED3 turn on

The problem is in all cases the LED3 turns on. It means that the data transmission failed.

With my IDE (IAR's Embedded Workbench) I compile this program code:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32_eval.h"


/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef enum { FAILED = 0, PASSED = !FAILED} TestStatus;

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define USARTy                   USART1
#define USARTy_GPIO              GPIOA /* PORT name*/
#define USARTy_CLK               RCC_APB2Periph_USART1
#define USARTy_GPIO_CLK          RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA
#define USARTy_RxPin             GPIO_Pin_10/* pin Rx name*/ 
#define USARTy_TxPin             GPIO_Pin_9 /* pin Tx name*/

#define USARTz                   USART2
#define USARTz_GPIO              GPIOA/* PORT name*/
#define USARTz_CLK               RCC_APB1Periph_USART2
#define USARTz_GPIO_CLK          RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA
#define USARTz_RxPin             GPIO_Pin_3/* pin Rx name*/
#define USARTz_TxPin             GPIO_Pin_2/* pin Tx name*/

#define TxBufferSize   (countof(TxBuffer))

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define countof(a)   (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
uint8_t TxBuffer[] = "Bufferrr";
uint8_t RxBuffer[8];
__IO uint8_t TxConteur = 0, RxConteur = 0;
volatile TestStatus TransferStatus = FAILED;  

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void RCC_Configuration(void);
void GPIO_Configuration(void);
TestStatus Buffercmp(uint8_t* pBuffer1, uint8_t* pBuffer2, uint16_t BufferLength);
__IO uint8_t index = 0;

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

int main(void)
{
  STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED1);
  STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED2);
  STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED3);
  STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED4);

/* System Clocks Configuration */
 RCC_Configuration();
/* Configure the GPIO ports */
GPIO_Configuration();

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 230400 /*115200*/; 
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength =USART_WordLength_8b ;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

  /* Configure USARTy */
  USART_Init(USART1,&USART_InitStructure);

  /* Enable the USARTy */
  USART_Cmd(USART1,ENABLE);

  while(TxConteur < TxBufferSize)
  {  
    /* Send one byte from USARTy to USARTz */
     USART_SendData(USARTy, TxBuffer[TxConteur++]);
    /* Loop until USARTy DR register is empty */ 
    while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_TC) == RESET)
    {
    }
    /* Store the received byte in RxBuffer */
    RxBuffer[RxConteur++] = USART_ReceiveData(USARTy) & 0xFF;
  }  

  /* Check the received data with the send ones */
  TransferStatus = Buffercmp(TxBuffer, RxBuffer, TxBufferSize);
  /* TransferStatus = FAILED, if the data transmitted from USARTy and 
     received by USARTz are different */
  if (TransferStatus == FAILED)
  {
      STM_EVAL_LEDOn(LED3);

  }
  else 
  {

   STM_EVAL_LEDOn(LED4);
  }

  while (1)
  {
  }
}

void RCC_Configuration(void)
{    

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA , ENABLE);

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1 , ENABLE);
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC , ENABLE);
}

void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure1,GPIO_InitStructure2;

  /* Configure USARTy Rx as input floating */
  GPIO_InitStructure1.GPIO_Pin =GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure1.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure1.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure1);

  /* Configure USARTy Tx as alternate function push-pull */
  GPIO_InitStructure2.GPIO_Pin =GPIO_Pin_9;
  GPIO_InitStructure2.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure2.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure2);
  /* Configure USARTz Tx as alternate function push-pull */


}


TestStatus Buffercmp(uint8_t* pBuffer1, uint8_t* pBuffer2, uint16_t BufferLength)
{
  while(BufferLength--)
  {
    if(*pBuffer1 != *pBuffer2)
    {
      return FAILED;
    }

    pBuffer1++;
    pBuffer2++;
  }

  return PASSED;  
}
```

Comment: Subminiature stylistic sidenote: you better not name your typedefs `TypeDef`, use `Context` or something like that.

Comment: Testing USART_FLAG_TC is a bad idea, that only tests if the byte was transmitted.  You need to test if a byte was received instead.  Use USART_FLAG_RXNE

Comment: @H2CO3 The STM "standard libraries" use that naming, it's ... annoying but hard to re-do.

Comment: @unwind Thanks, good to know. Well, that was not a particularly wise decision of the writers of the library, then.

Comment: I replaced USART_FLAG_TC by USART_FLAG_RXNE and it works.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Like explained in a comment by Hans Passant, the OP was testing the flag `USART_FLAG_TC` (Transmission Completed) instead of the flag `USART_FLAG_RXNE` (RX buffer Not Empty).